# Keeping track of concurrent Tasks

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, collections

I'm writing a polling system against SQL Server.  When tasks are retrieved, they are off-loaded to a new thread using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.  The whole thing is inside an endless loop and I want to allow only N concurrent tasks.

```
while(true)
{
    // create connection

    while(_concurrentTasks < _allowedTasks)
    { 
        // get job info

        if(!reader.HasRows) break; // no work to do.

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // fill JobInfo entity from reader

            _taskCollection.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessJob(jobInfo)));

            _concurrentTasks++;
        }
    }

    // could break for 1 of 2 reasons, threshold met or nothing to do
    if((_concurrentTasks < _allowedTasks)
    {
        // sleep for a predetermined period of time
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
    else
    {
        // wait for one thread to complete and then get more jobs
        Task.WaitAny(_taskCollection.ToArray);   
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which collection would be best to use in this situation or how to clean up the tasks that have been completed.

If I put the cleanup code in the task itself, I can use `List<Task>` along with the `Task.CurrentId` property to identify the item in the collection, but I don't believe I can dispose of the Task object in the collection within the task itself; also note that the collection would have to be threadsafe.

If I put some kind of cleanup code outside the task (in the main thread), I wouldn't need a threadsafe collection, but I have no idea when a task completes in the main thread.

So, which collection should I use to maintain a list/array of concurrent tasks so I can use `WaitAny()` and how can I clean up the list when one completes?

Comment: Why do you want to limit it to N concurrent tasks?  Are you experiencing a performance impact from having too many run at once?  Generally the TPL is good at running the "right" number.

Comment: @ChrisShain - I'm going to have several of these processes running at the same time. If I don't throttle it, one process can hog all the jobs and they'll simply stack up in the ThreadPool queue.

Comment: You could look at schedulers others made, specifically the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler.cs. http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/specialized-task-schedulers-in-net-4-par/228800428

Comment: 'I'm writing a polling system against SQL Server' - can you not use a trigger and maybe stored proc?

Comment: @MartinJames - I wanted to use Broker Services, but management shot down the idea, so I'm stuck with a polling service.

Comment: @KeesDijk - I looked at those schedulers, very interesting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use an array and loop through it when necessary:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[_allowedTasks];

while(true)  
{  
    // create connection  

    while(_concurrentTasks < _allowedTasks)  
    {   
        // get job info  

        if(!reader.HasRows) break; // no work to do.  

        while(reader.Read())  
        {  

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tasks[i] == null || tasks[i].IsCompleted)
                {
                    // Dispose of Task at position i

                    nextSlot = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // fill JobInfo entity from reader  

            tasks[nextSlot] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessJob(jobInfo));  

            _concurrentTasks++;  
        }  
    }  

    // could break for 1 of 2 reasons, threshold met or nothing to do  
    if((_concurrentTasks < _allowedTasks)  
    {  
        // sleep for a predetermined period of time  
        Thread.Sleep(60000);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        // wait for one thread to complete and then get more jobs  
        Task.WaitAny(_taskCollection.ToArray);     
    }  
}
```